# Gitlab Pipeline email - including the actual error

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd

I know about Gitlab's Project --> Setting --> integrations -->Pipelines emails, but is there a way to enrich the 'failed pipeline email' with the **actual error** ?

I find it very inefficient to have to open the email, find and click on the link in the email, click on the failed pipeline step, and only then see what compilation or unit-test error made it into the system.

If that email would simply include (or even start with) the last 25 lines of the pipeline's output that would help a lot. Then I could fix the error and wouldn't even have to go gitlab and back to try another build. I'm counting 2-3 unnecessary clicks in this workflow.

Note: I'm using Java with maven - but this question applies to all languages, all types of projects.

Answer (score 1):

This was possible in the past but intentionally removed.
See this merge request why:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/42395

Comment: thanks for the info. Too bad, though.